# Why is COUNT(*) trimmed the result without GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, count

From w3schools

> Definition and Usage
>
> The COUNT() function returns the number of records returned by a select query.

Consider the below two queries

Query 1

```
SELECT name
FROM testtable

name
----
tom
peter
mary
foo
bar
```

Query 2

```
SELECT name
FROM testtable
GROUP BY name

name
----
tom
peter
mary
foo
bar
```

Both queries return the same result.
However, adding `COUNT(*)` in the `SELECT` statement, the result differs.

Query 3

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM testtable

name | COUNT(*)
---------------
tom  |   5
```

Query 4

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM testtable
GROUP BY name

name  | COUNT(*)
---------------
tom   |  1
peter |  1
mary  |  1
foo   |  1
bar   |  1
```

**The question is 'Why is COUNT(*) trimmed the result in query 3?'**

My expectation

```
SELECT name, COUNT(*)
FROM testtable

name  | COUNT(*)
---------------
tom   |  5
peter |  5
mary  |  5
foo   |  5
bar   |  5
```

In analog to

```
SELECT name, 'test'
FROM testtable

name  |  test
---------------
tom   |  test
peter |  test
mary  |  test
foo   |  test
bar   |  test
```

Comment: Haven't done much MySql lately so I can't answer but really I'm more surprised query 3 is valid SQL

Comment: Your "Query 3" will error out on every single RDBMS on the planet except pre-5.7 version of Mysql. If your column in your `SELECT` statement isn't being aggregated via a function (sum, max, avg, etc) then it MUST appear in your GROUP BY. In pre-5.7 versions of mysql omitting this is like telling that system "Assume that I don't want to group by `Name` and just choose one at random" which is a terrible "feature". For the record post-5.7 version of mysql will also allow these through without error, but only if the ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY flag is set to false.

Comment: I am using 8.0.25. Seems the ```ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY``` flag is default disable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Normally (that is: for most DMSB other than MySQL), requesting "normal" columns in conjunction with aggregated columns is an error. You should only request aggregated columns with columns named in the `group by` part of your query.

For MySQL its behavior can be influenced with the `sql_mode`. To quote [the documentation for MySQL 8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/counting-rows.html):

> If you name columns to select in addition to the `COUNT()` value, a
> `GROUP BY` clause should be present that names those same columns.
> Otherwise, the following occurs:
>
> If the `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` SQL mode is enabled, an error occurs:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT owner, COUNT(*) FROM pet;
> ERROR 1140 (42000): In aggregated query without GROUP BY, expression
> #1 of SELECT list contains nonaggregated column 'menagerie.pet.owner';
> this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by
> ```
>
> If `ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY` is not enabled, the query is processed by
> treating all rows as a single group, but the value selected for each
> named column is nondeterministic. The server is free to select the
> value from any row:
>
> ```
> mysql> SET sql_mode = '';
> Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
>
> mysql> SELECT owner, COUNT(*) FROM pet;
> +--------+----------+
> | owner  | COUNT(*) |
> +--------+----------+
> | Harold |        8 |
> +--------+----------+
> 1 row in set (0.00 sec)
> ```
>
> See also [Section 12.20.3, “MySQL Handling of GROUP
> BY”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html).
> See [Section 12.20.1, “Aggregate Function
> Descriptions”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)
> for information about `COUNT(expr)` behavior and related
> optimizations.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you have got enough explanation on the reason why your query is behaving the way it is doing.

To answer your question, if you need count with all rows, you can use leverage Windows Function like below (works in MySQL 8.0)

```
SELECT name, count(*) over () as total_count
FROM testable
```